# Add a query string to ALL links on site

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, links, rewrite-rules

Our client would like to embed his site into an iframe in their software backend. I get a query string on the first link but need to make sure that string persists across URLs for all links and navigation on the iframed site. How do I do that?

This only needs to happen when the query string is present.

EDIT: Come this far, just don't know what to do to persist the clean=true query where it appears.

```
function add_rewrite_rules($aRules) {
    $aNewRules = array('^/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?clean=$matches[1]');
    $aRules = $aNewRules + $aRules;
    return $aRules;
}

add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules');
function add_query_vars($qvars) {
    $qvars[] = "clean";    
    return $qvars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use some JavaScript to change all links on page load. It's maybe not the best solution, but it works. I've written a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ahendwh2/9L0wyjs6/) for demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your Question, you need to hook into most of the Link Filters (which are listed here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference#Link_Filters ) and then add the query to them if the queryvar "clean" is set.

Happy Coding,
Kuchenundkakao

Comment: This will not solve the problem with links in the content.